# How to see if the two's complement of a number x can be represented in n number of bits

Tags: c

- fitsBits - return 1 if x can be represented as an
- n-bit, two's complement integer.
- 1 <= n <= 32
- Examples: fitsBits(5,3) = 0, fitsBits(-4,3) = 1
- Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

My code is the following:

```
int fitsBits(int x, int n) {
    int twos = ~x + 1; //two's complement
    int ans;
    ans = (twos >> (n);
    ans = !ans;
    return ans;
}
```

Working it on paper, it seems to work correctly but it fails when actually tested and I'm not sure why.

Comment: That can't be your **real** code. it doesn't even compile, much less run. Is there an extraneous `(` there or was that intentional. Regardless, were it I, I'd start by using a *debugger*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are working on a 2s complement machine (vice sign-magnitude or some other kind of arithmetic) and need to avoid loops and conditionals as well. This is clearly some kind of puzzle, so let's not worry about portability and assume 32-bit `int`s.

If the value is positive, all bits from `n-1` through the highest order bit of the `int` must be zeros.  If the value is negative, the same bits must be ones. So one approach is to check those bits for the correct value.

This is equivalent to checking whether `x >> (~0+n)` is all zeros if `x` is positive and all ones otherwise. It "shifts out" the bits that are free to have any value.

We can also construct a mask that's all zeros if `x` is positive, else ones, with `x >> 31`.

Finally, we can check equality of any `int`s `a` and `b` using `!(a ^ b)`.

Putting all this together, you'd get:

```
int fitBits(int val, int nbits) {
  return !((val >> 31) ^ (val >> (~0 + nbits)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the log base 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fitsBits(unsigned int v, unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int r = 0; // lg(v)
    while (v >>= 1) {
        r++;
    }
    if(r >= n) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main () {
    printf("  5,3 => %d\n", fitsBits( 5,3));
    printf(" -4,3 => %d\n", fitsBits(-4,3));
}
```

output:
  5,3 => 0
 -4,3 => 1